# Booting error on 12.04

Tags: boot

When I'm booting Ubuntu 12.04 this error is showing:

```
render error detected, EIR: 0x00000010
page table error
PGTBL_ER: 0x00000100
[drm:i915_report_and_clear_eir] *ERROR* EIR stuck: 0x00000010, masking
```

Comment: It seems to be your graphics problem. Can you provide some more information exactly what did you do in last? Also edit your question and provide the output of these commands: `sudo dpkg -l | grep video-intel`, `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a` and `sudo lspci | grep VGA`.

Answer (score 0):

See also this thread in Linuxquestions:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/render-error-detected-eir-0x00000000-877013/